# Cucumber and Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, tdd, cucumber, bdd

So I am wondering if anyone is familiar or has done any work with cucumber and Silverlight.  I currently have a template directory and build file that will create RSpec tests using Bacon (light weight RSpec).  I have been looking into SpecFlow and Cuke2Nuke but almost everything I have seen works with general .net code not silverlight code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org) is an open-source project to do BDD with .NET. From version 3.1.2 it also supports Silverlight. You can check the sample at: http://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/BowlingKata/BowlingKata-Silverlight-MsTest/

SpecFlow is using a plain text definition format (Gherkin - same format as cucumber), and it generates unit tests from it (in case of Silverlight, MsTest is supported).

You can also check the wiki about the SpecFlow Silvelight integration: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/silverlight-support